# improving xor neural network in tensorflow and using dense as an input layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, xor

I am trying to build a neural network in tf as a beginners challenge, and my model is not very good meaning many times it will not be very accurate (although sometimes accuracy is 1 but most of the time it isn't, and even then the loss is high.

So I have two questions:

1. How can I improve this NN?
2. What Is the difference between using `Input` as the input layer and using `Dense`?

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,)))
#model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# X_train, Y_train = ([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]], [[0], [1], [1], [0]])
X_train = tf.cast([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]], tf.float32)
Y_train = tf.cast([0, 1, 1, 0], tf.float32)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=500, steps_per_epoch=1)


print(model.predict([[0, 1]]))
print(model.predict([[1, 1]]))
print(model.predict([[1, 0]]))
print(model.predict([[0, 0]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several obvious problems with above code:

First off, the `steps_per_epoch=1` parameter means that for each epoch, your model will only see 1 example. Very inefficient. remove that parameter.

Next up, the 500 epochs are not nearly enough. Without pretraining, NN-s take a lot of time to train, even on the simplest problems. I just ran your code and in about 3500 epochs, it converges to the optimal solution.

---

Haven't tried it, but you also can try a higher learning rate, like this:

```py
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=5e-2) #for example
model.compile(optimizer=optimzer, ...)
```

Also, if you know how to use callbacks, you can always use `EarlyStopping` callback to make the model run until the best model is found.

About early stopping:
If you use early stopping, you *must* also use a separate validation set. It's the validation set that tells you when it's the right time to stop training. Early stopping is one of the easiest and (in my opinion) one of the most useful regularization techniques in the field today.

So, if used with a validation set, no problem of stopping too early. Default parameters just to the trick.

Also, if you have many (+50) epochs, try plotting the history to gain insights.

Like this:

```py
hist = model.fit(...)
plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
```

If the line is bouncing at the end, you probably need `EarlyStopping` or maybe even [Learning rate decay](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/ExponentialDecay).

Ask me if anything else seems vague.
Cheers.

Comment: Sounds great thank you! I have two tiny questions remaining: Is `EarlyStopping` creating any risk of stopping too early? Meaning If we had continued we would have found a better model? The second question is: Is it ok that sometimes I get (with 2500 epochs) 100% accuracy (most of the time) and sometimes only 75%?

Comment: @bendaMan that's a good question. see the updated answer.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for the thorough answer, now a lot more is clear :)   about the question of the accuracy I mentioned in the previous comment, should I be worried or is that normal?

Comment: @bendaMan I tried but was unable to reproduce that result. Are you sure the source code is unchainged? My model always gets to the 1.0 accuracy.

Comment: The code I used can be found [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/80a5679b)

Comment: @bendaMan Yes, I just got the .75 accuracy at 2500 epochs. Turns out it needs even more epochs than that. In some cases it needed even 4000 epochs. Try running with 4000 epochs. Does it ever fail to reach 1.0 accuracy now?

Comment: yes it does fail sometimes :(   how does one know when it's enough epochs?

Comment: It sounds much like [the JQuery joke](https://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif), but you should really use `EarlyStopping` for that. It would solve that problem. Just don't forget to set epochs to some really big number, 10 ** 6 for example.

Comment: Loved the joke XD  thanks for all the help, I've learnt a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should try to put more neurons in your hidden layer. I've tried with 64 and it worked fine.

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
```

**Input layer** is configured to receive your initial data, that means you can custom the input shape data of your NN and it explicitly asks for the shape of the input. When you use dense, you configure how many Neurons you need in your layer, aditionally you can custom the Activation Function there.

Notice that you use **dense**  for setting your output layer where the number of neurons is the number of classes you want to predict (one in this case).

Comment: thanks for your interest in this question. Wouldn't you agree that 64 units seem like overkill for such a trivial task?

Comment: So it seems as if there aren't many reasons to use `Input layer` and it doesn't add much functionality, except for maybe more clarity